# convert list of lists to list of vectors in R

Tags: r

I have a list of list of numbers that I want to change to a list of vectors of numbers.  How could I do that?

Here's what I have,

```
>coords
[[1]]
[1] -106.24328   39.00774

[[2]]
[1] -106.18677   38.83261

[[3]]
[1] -106.1493   38.8303

> class(coords[1])
[1] "list"
> class(coords[1[1]])
[1] "list"
>
```

What I want is

```
>coords
[1] -106.24328   39.00774
[2] -106.18677   38.83261
[3] -106.1493   38.8303
```

Comment: @akrun I think you're overthinking it. These are coordinates, so he's presumably just looking for rows of `longitude | latitude`

Comment: The first output is what I have now and it is definitely a list of lists.  The second is what I envision the output would look like if I have what I need.

Comment: @akrun Yeah - he's just a little confused/unfamiliar with the terminology.

Comment: Thanks akrun, that worked!   If you put it in an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: By the way, Senor, how could I have worded it more accurately?

Comment: what you have is actual a `list` of `vectors` (`[1] -106.24328   39.00774` is not a list) and what you want is a `data.frame` or `matrix`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `coords` object seems to be a `list`.  To convert it to a `matrix` with 2 columns, we can `rbind` the `list` elements.

```
m1 <- do.call(rbind, coords)
```