# Turning Leaflet Feature into SF Feature

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet, spatial, r-sf

**Edit:** I am using [leaflet.extras](https://github.com/bhaskarvk/leaflet.extras/blob/master/inst/examples/draw.R) and the `addDrawToolbar()` function to my leaflet map. Within shiny, I am reading the outputs of a users input using `shape = input$[mapID]_draw_new_feature`. I'd like to be able to turn this shape object into an sf object which then I can use to find overlapping features using the sf package.

How do I turn this object which is already a spatial object (from Leaflet) into a polygon using the sf package? I've tried a couple of things, including trying to break down the geometry into a list of vectors using the linked SO post, but I still can't quite get it to work. I feel like it should be easier than it is... or I'm missing something.

```
Browse[2]> dput(shape)
list(type = "Feature", properties = list(`_leaflet_id` = 1063L, 
    feature_type = "rectangle"), geometry = list(type = "Polygon", 
    coordinates = list(list(list(-100.357361, 32.632436), list(
        -100.357361, 32.930318), list(-99.769592, 32.930318), 
        list(-99.769592, 32.632436), list(-100.357361, 32.632436)))))
```

```
Browse[2]> st_polygon(shape)
Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : is.numeric(x) is not TRUE
Browse[2]> st_polygon(shape$geometry)
Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : is.numeric(x) is not TRUE
Browse[2]> test <- st_sf(shape$geometry)
Error in st_sf(shape$geometry) : 
  no simple features geometry column present
```

[convert list of lists to list of vectors in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32381358/convert-list-of-lists-to-list-of-vectors-in-r)

Comment: `geojsonsf::geojson_sf(jsonify::to_json(lst, unbox = T))` will work. However, what do you mean by "a spatail object from Leaflet)" ? Your list object is `geojson`, but formatted as a list in R. I suspect this conversion to a list can / should be avoided and you can use the geojson directly.

Comment: Thanks @SymbolixAU! Will give that a shot and let you know if it works. I edited my question with a bit more context to answer your question about where 'shape' comes from. I didn't know it was returning geojson. If there are ways to avoid this, and I should, happy to do so.